How to bypass "Your connection is not private" in Nightwatch.js?
I'm trying to test a site on https://localhost with a self-signed certificate. I keep getting the "Your connection is not private" with the Advanced and Back to safety buttons followed by the "Proceed to localhost (unsafe)" link when Advanced is clicked.
I feel I have tried everything in nightwatch.conf.js:
chrome: {
  desiredCapabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    'goog:chromeOptions': {
      // More info on Chromedriver: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/
      //
      // w3c:false tells Chromedriver to run using the legacy JSONWire protocol (not required in Chrome 78)
      w3c: true,
      args: [
        //'--no-sandbox',
        '--ignore-certificate-errors',
        '--ignore-ssl-errors=yes',
        '--allow-insecure-localhost',
        //'--headless'
      ]
    }
  },

and also enabling the Allow invalid certificates for resources loaded from localhost. setting in chrome://flags
Still I get the warning every time I spin up my test. If I'm quick enough I can click my way past the warning and my test runs just fine. I would like to run by itself though 
Nightwatch.js v3.6.0
Chrome v123.0.6312.106
Anyone...?
